# JacksonJsonProvider set non_null inclusion in spring xml

Tags: jackson, cxfrs

Hi following is my cxfrs server configuration

```
<cxf:rsServer id="itemService"
        address="{{esb.item.rest.address}}"
        serviceClass="com.test.esb.service.flm.ItemServiceImpl"
        loggingFeatureEnabled="false">
        <cxf:providers>
            <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
        </cxf:providers>
    </cxf:rsServer>
```

I need to configure Inclusion.NON_NULL here so that it can exclude the null fields from the generated gson string. Any idea how i can achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a customized provider instance using your own factory method. Here is an example factory class:

```
public class JacksonJsonProviderFactory {

    public static JacksonJsonProvider create() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        return new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper);        
    }
}
```

And here is an example [XML Blueprint](http://aries.apache.org/modules/blueprint.html) fragment:

```
 <cxf:providers>
       <bean class="JacksonJsonProviderFactory" factory-method="create"/>
 </cxf:providers>
```